# Split a list of days into a list of months which contain a list of days

Tags: elixir

I have a list of maps which include date. I don't know how long that list is (can be multiple years of days). All I know is that the list is sorted by date and doesn't have duplicate dates.

Example:

```
[
%{date: ~D[2017-01-01], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-02], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-03], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-04], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-05], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-06], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-07], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-08], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-09], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-10], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-11], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-12], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-13], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-14], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-15], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-16], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-17], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-18], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-19], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-20], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-21], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-22], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-23], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-24], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-25], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-26], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-27], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-28], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-29], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-30], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-31], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-02-01], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-02-02], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-02-03], y: ["x"]}
]
```

I want a list of months which contain the days:

```
[
[
%{date: ~D[2017-01-01], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-02], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-03], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-04], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-05], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-06], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-07], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-08], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-09], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-10], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-11], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-12], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-13], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-14], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-15], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-16], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-17], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-18], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-19], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-20], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-21], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-22], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-23], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-24], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-25], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-26], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-27], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-28], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-29], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-30], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-01-31], y: ["x"]}
],
[
%{date: ~D[2017-02-01], y: ["x"]},
%{date: ~D[2017-02-02], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-02-03], y: ["x"]}
]
]
```

Because each months has a different length (plus the leap year problem) I have no idea how to split the list. Can this be done?

Comment: FWIW, `Enum.group_by/3` you were introduced 3 hours before in the answer to your previous question, easily does the same trick (while `Enum.chunk_by/2` is definitely a better choice here): `list |> Enum.group_by(fn %{date: %{year: year, month: month}} -> {year, month} end) |> Map.values`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [`Enum.chunk_by/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_by/2), returning a tuple of the year and the month of the date of each element in the callback function. This will split the list every time the year or month changes. (Just `month` won't work correctly if your list contains e.g. 2016-01-01 followed by 2017-01-01.)

```
list = [
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-01], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-02], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-03], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-04], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-05], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-06], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-07], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-08], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-09], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-10], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-11], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-12], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-13], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-14], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-15], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-16], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-17], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-18], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-19], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-20], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-21], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-22], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-23], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-24], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-25], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-26], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-27], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-28], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-29], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-30], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-31], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-02-01], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-02-02], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-02-03], y: ["x"]}
]

list
|> Enum.chunk_by(fn %{date: %{year: year, month: month}} -> {year, month} end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[[%{date: ~D[2017-01-01], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-02], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-03], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-04], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-05], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-06], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-07], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-08], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-09], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-10], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-11], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-12], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-13], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-14], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-15], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-16], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-17], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-18], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-19], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-20], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-21], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-22], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-23], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-24], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-25], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-26], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-27], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-28], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-29], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-01-30], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-01-31], y: ["x"]}],
 [%{date: ~D[2017-02-01], y: ["x"]}, %{date: ~D[2017-02-02], y: ["x"]},
  %{date: ~D[2017-02-03], y: ["x"]}]]
```